# Prevent focus/tabbing into non visible element in UI

Tags: wpf

For example, I have `Grid` with two rows and `GridSplitter` between them. When one the rows is not visible in UI (eg. splitter is all the way on top; real case scenario is more complicated with nested controls) elements are still reachable via tab key - I would like to prevent that.

I am aware of `IsVisible` property of `FrameworkElement` (is true even for such elements) and/or `IsEnabled`/`IsTabStop` and `KeyboardNavigation` class in general, but none of them solves my problem. My elements are usable etc., just not currently visible in UI because of grid splitter. Basically only framework elements which can be reached by mouse should also participate in tab key functionality.

Simplest case when it can be reproduced is following content of main window (move splitter to upper most position).

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once"/>
        <GridSplitter Height="10" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_Problem" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Result should be that non-visible elements should be skipped and next visible element should be focused instead. This functionality should be compatible with `KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation`.

Edit 1: changed sample a little in order to show, that `PART_Problem` keeps `ActualHeight` to some non-zero value, which eliminates solutions based on size changes.

Comment: Have a look at an attached property, this way you could make one for `FrameworkElement` [example here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vikie4u/attached-properties-in-wpf/)

Comment: Question is on what the attached property (or in other form - behaviour) should react. `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` is the closest one, but it does not inform whether element is being focused because of `FocusNavigationDirection.Next` or `FocusNavigationDirection.Previous`. Also the not having correct size on element or some event regarding this is problem.

Comment: I think you should look at the min size of the container (not the textbox), so if it is below 10 or whatever your margin is then set visibility to collapsed. You can do that in xaml and with a use of converter.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property `Focusable="False"` in XAML

Comment: That is just another static property like `IsTabStop`. I need something dynamic, like event (or correctly behaving WPF in general).